# iOS 8 Print Interaction Controller has 0 height on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios8, airprint

I'm trying to present an instance of UIPrintInteractionController to use AirPrint to print an image. At first it seemed like nothing was going on, but inside the delegate method `printInteractionControllerDidPresentPrinterOptions:` I use `self.presentedViewController` to get info about the supposed "presented" Print Interaction Controller. Turns out that it has a width of 19.000 and a height of 0.000... It doesn't seem that there's a way to access the viewcontroller before it's actually presented since it's all auto-generated in the framework, and I haven't been able to successfully modify its frame post-presenting. Anyone else encounter this issue and/or found a work-around?

```
- (void)printBadgeImage:(UIImage *)image {

    UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printInfo.jobName = BADGE_PRINT_JOB;
    printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
    pic.printInfo = printInfo;
    pic.printingItem = image;
    pic.delegate = self;

    UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler =
    ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController,
      BOOL completed,
      NSError *error) {

        if (completed) {

            NSLog(@"Print job completed");

        } else if (!completed && error) {

            NSLog(@"Print job error");
            NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"An error occured while printing: %@", error];
            UIAlertView *alert = [[DOSimpleAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                  message:errorString];

            [alert show];

        } else {

           NSLog(@"Print job incomplete without error");
        }
    };

    [pic presentFromRect:self.view.frame
                  inView:self.view
                animated:YES
       completionHandler:completionHandler];

}

- (void)printInteractionControllerDidPresentPrinterOptions:(UIPrintInteractionController *)printInteractionController {

    NSLog(@"Did present");
    // following printed <UIPrintInteractionController: 0x145d1a30>
    NSLog(@"The Print Interaction Controller: %@", printInteractionController);
    // following printed <UINavigationController: 0x145d3840>
    NSLog(@"The presented view: %@", self.presentedViewController);
    UIViewController *presented = self.presentedViewController;
    // following printed 19.000000
    NSLog(@"Presented view width: %f", presented.view.frame.size.width);
    // following printed 0.000000
    NSLog(@"Presented view height: %f", presented.view.frame.size.height);
    // following printed 0.000000
    NSLog(@"Presented view x: %f", presented.view.frame.origin.x);
    // following printed 0.000000
    NSLog(@"Presented view y: %f", presented.view.frame.origin.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that prints an image but I haven't looked at the code in a LONG time. But here is the blurb, hope it helps.

```
NSData *moneyData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
if(pic && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData: moneyData] ) {

    pic.delegate = self;

    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printInfo.jobName = @"MONEY";
    printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
    pic.printInfo = printInfo;
    pic.showsPageRange = YES;
    pic.printingItem = moneyData;

    [pic presentFromBarButtonItem:self.printButton animated:YES completionHandler:nil];
}
```

If I remember right there is something special about how you present it. You may want to try from a bar button item like mine.